# Batch- Associate variable values based on filename extract

Tags: date, batch-file, extract, filenames, classification

I have filename that look like this
20120528_Sales_Store_001.pdf
20120529_Sales_Store_001.pdf
etc

I need to extract the date from the filename and then associate it to 2 variables
Month
Week

So for each date in the calendar I need to be able to associate the week number and the month name.

**Those are FISCAL calendar week&month so it has nothing to do with the actual calendar.**

Example

20120528 would be Week 4 and Month April

20120529 would be Week 5 and Month May

Since the fiscal calendar moves from year to year, I know that I will have to redo it every year but im looking for a way to minimize the work that needs to be done.

So I would like to maybe setup something like

Week4 is from ThisDate to ThisDate and is also in the Month of April

Fiscal April would be from 20120403 to 20120430

and count Week 1-2-3-4 (weeks starting every sunday)

Week5 is from ThisDate to ThisDate and is also in the Month of May

Fiscal May would be from 20120501 to 20120528

It is always, 2 month that has 4 weeks and then the 3rd month have 5 weeks.

etc

Or else, I will have to do it once for every day.. which is going to be looong to do and loooong to update every year.

I will need to use the Month and Week variable for directory classification afterwards and that is why I need it.

Comment: what is your operating system?The date arithmetic with batch will be pain in the ass.If you are running Win7 it will be far more easier because of the powershell. Otherwise will be better to use vbscript/jscript which can be used on every windows system.

Comment: I assume your fiscal months consist of whole weeks. You state your weeks start on Sunday, yet fiscal April 2012 starts on 20120403 - a Tuesday. Something is wrong somewhere. Is April the beginning of your fiscal year? Does your fiscal month start on the 1st full week of the month? or end on the last full week of the month? (or something else entirely?). Once the rules are established, it should not be too difficult to create a script that writes a look up file containing every day of the year, along with the month name and week number. But the rules must be known.

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake. I was looking at 2011 calendar. I am sorry.

April 2012 would be from APril 1st to April 28th
May is from April 29th to May 26 etc..

Always 4 weeks, 4 weeks and then 5 weeks.


I am testing on Windows 7 but it will operated on a Windows 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set the_file=20120528_Sales_Store_001.pdf

for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%F in ("!the_file!") do (
   set date=%%F
   set month=!date:~4,6!
   set day=!date:~6!
   set /a week_of_the_month=!day! / 7
   set /a modolus="!day! %% 7"
   if !modolus! GEQ 4 (
       set /a week_of_the_month=!week_of_the_month!+1
   )

   echo !the_file! is in the !week_of_the_month!th week of the month
   echo !the_file! >> week_!week_of_the_month!_of_!month!_month.txt

)
endlocal
```

this should write the file name to a week_XX_of_XX_month.txt fime .This can be wrapped in another `FOR /F` that will traverse the files.The files also can be copied and with a little bit more `SETs` the number of the month can be changed to it's name.I couldn't find better way to calculate the week in the month.Do you need more improvements?

**UPDATE:**

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
pushd %traverse_dir% 
for /f %%D  in ('dir /b *.pdf ^|findstr "[1234567890_]" ') do (
        for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%F in ("%%D") do (
           set date=%%F
           set month=!date:~4,6!
           set day=!date:~6!
           set /a week_of_the_month=!day! / 7
           set /a modolus="!day! %% 7"
           if !modolus! GEQ 4 (
               set /a week_of_the_month=!week_of_the_month!+1
           )

           echo !the_file! is in the !week_of_the_month!th week of the month
           echo !the_file! >> week_!week_of_the_month!_of_!month!_month.txt

        )
)
endlocal
popd
```

Comment: Thank you very much Npocmaka!
How would you do the other /F so it would do all the files in the current directory automatically?

I am testing on Windows 7 but it will operated on a Windows 2008